# How to configure which QToolbars will be able to collapse when resizing QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I need to collapse some toolbars when resizing main window. Others should be always visible. I can use setPriority method for QActions inside toolbars, it helps to make important actions visible while collapsing. But I need something like this for toolbars.

Answer (score 0):

You can override [`virtual void QWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) of your main window class to hide toolbars.

Something like this

```
void MyMainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event)
{
    //hiding some toolbars
    someToolBar->hide();

    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Try to call `QWidget::setMinimumSize(int minw, int minh)` for the important toolbars. Maybe it will work.